# How can I dynamically change my source of data with the on_change function of a select/dropdown?

Tags: bokeh

I have a graph being generated from hard coded ColumnDataSource.

My graph values need to change depending on what my user selects from the dropdown.

My update() function doesn't work the way I want it to. My old 'source' and 'NEWsource' are in the same format when printed out, I just cant get the changes to display on the plot.

```
from os.path import dirname, join
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import PreText, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure

DEFAULT_TICKERS = ['giode', 'commerce_center', 'web_forms']

def load_data_depending_on_dropdown_value(ticker):
    ...

def get_data(ticker):
    ...data processing...
    return data

# Make my dropdown, aka. ticker
ticker = Select(value='giode', options=DEFAULT_TICKERS)

# ORIGINAL SOURCE - HARDCODED
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
        counts=[5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6,2]
        )
    )
source_static = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
        counts=[5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6,2]
        )
    )

# Make a plot
p = figure(x_range=source.data['message'], plot_height=250)
p.vbar(x='message', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0

# Called when ticker, aka. dropdown, gets changed
def ticker_changed(attrname, old, new):
    print(attrname, old, new)
    update()

# CONTAINING MY NEW SOURCE
def update(selected=None):
    t1_Value = ticker.value
    newData = get_data(t1_Value)
    newMessages = newData.message.tolist()
    newCounts = newData.counts.tolist()

    NEWsource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(message=newMessages, counts=newCounts))

    # Compare the old source with my new source:
    print("Original source.data: " , source.data , "New data: " , NEWsource.data)

    source.data = NEWsource.data
    source_static.data = NEWsource.data
        # This part works fine
    p.title.text = '%s Plot' % (t1_Value)


ticker.on_change('value', ticker_changed)


widgets = column(ticker)
main_row = row(widgets, p)

update()

curdoc().add_root(main_row)
curdoc().title = "Stocks"
```

What's stopping the NEWsource from reaching the plot?

Plot correctly displaying hard-coded source:

[image]

When I try to update the plot from my dynamic NEWsource with some jumbled up values in the top corner:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in Bokeh v1.1.0. One remark: it is recommended to replace just the `data` of the `ColumnDataSource` object instead of creating a new `ColumnDataSource` each time.

```
def update():
    source.data = get_data(ticker.value)
    p.title.text = '%s Plot' % (ticker.value)
```

Here is your full code with this small change in the update(). Run it from Terminal: `bokeh serve --show app.py`

```
from os.path import dirname, join
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import PreText, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure

DEFAULT_TICKERS = ['giode', 'commerce_center', 'web_forms']

def load_data_depending_on_dropdown_value(ticker):
    pass

def get_data(ticker):
    if ticker == 'giode':
        return    dict(
            message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
            counts=[5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6,2]
            )
    elif ticker == 'commerce_center':
        return    dict(
            message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
            counts=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            )
    elif ticker == 'web_forms':
        return    dict(
            message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
            counts=[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
            )      

# Make my dropdown, aka. ticker
ticker = Select(value='giode', options=DEFAULT_TICKERS)

# ORIGINAL SOURCE - HARDCODED
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
        counts=[5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6,2]
        )
    )
source_static = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        message=['BPN Broken', 'BPN Off', 'BPN Faulty', 'BPN Rain', 'BPN Fire', 'BPN Tornado', 'BPN STAFF DAY OFF'],
        counts=[5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6,2]
        )
    )

# Make a plot
p = figure(x_range=source.data['message'], plot_height=250)
p.vbar(x='message', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0

# Called when ticker, aka. dropdown, gets changed
def ticker_changed(attrname, old, new):
    print(attrname, old, new)
    update()

# CONTAINING MY NEW SOURCE
# def update(selected=None):
#     t1_Value = ticker.value
#     newData = get_data(t1_Value)
#     newMessages = newData.message.tolist()
#     newCounts = newData.counts.tolist()
#  
#     NEWsource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(message=newMessages, counts=newCounts))
# 
#     # Compare the old source with my new source:
#     print("Original source.data: " , source.data , "New data: " , NEWsource.data)
# 
#     source.data = NEWsource.data
#     source_static.data = NEWsource.data
#         
#     # This part works fine
#     p.title.text = '%s Plot' % (t1_Value)

def update(selected = None):
    newData = get_data(ticker.value)
    source.data = newData
    source_static.data = newData
    p.title.text = '%s Plot' % (ticker.value)

ticker.on_change('value', ticker_changed)

widgets = column(ticker)
main_row = row(widgets, p)

update()

curdoc().add_root(main_row)
curdoc().title = "Stocks"
```

[image]